# Period.between does not include the last day in Java

Tags: java, period

```
Period difference = Period.between(01.01.2018,31.01.2018)
```

`difference.getMonths()` gives zero and `difference.getDays()` gives 30 days, anyway to include the last day ?

Comment: That's how the method is defined: start date inclusive, end date exclusive; and it makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is utterly simple: just call `plusDays(1)` on the resulting period.

`Period.between` does not include the end day on purpose. In order to include the last day, you must manually add one day yourself.

---

This pattern of including the start point and excluding the end point is quite common. For example, `String.substring(int startIndex, int endIndex)` also follows this pattern, as well as `IntStream.range(int startInclusive, int endExclusive)`

Comment: if the number of days is 30 and the month just contains 30 days, then it does not make sense right ?

Comment: From the javadoc: This method adds the specified amount to the days field incrementing themonth and year fields as necessary to ensure the result remains valid

Comment: `plusDays` simply adds one day to the period, nothing more. This may cause the month and year to be incremented accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

It is in the documentation (end date exclusive):

> The start date is included, but the end date is not.

You could simply add one day to your enddate via `endDate.plusDays(1)`